# Using multiple COUNTs and SUMs in a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a tables called **pages**, **page_views**, **page_items** and **page_votes**. The latter three tables contain a **page_id** foreign key in order to keep a record of each individual view, item and vote that belongs to a page.

When I query a page, I also want to retrieve **COUNT page_views**, **COUNT page_items** and **SUM page_votes.vote**.

I have pasted a query below. It retrieves the total number of views. I've made various attempts to add items and votes to it, but the result is either a syntax error or views/items/votes returned as an identical and "wrong" number, probably due to the way I am joining.

How can I add items and votes to this query?

```
SELECT
  Page.*,
  COUNT(*) AS views
FROM pages AS Page 
INNER JOIN page_views AS PageView
  ON Page.id = PageView.page_id 
GROUP BY Page.id 
ORDER BY views DESC   
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will select `TOP 10 viewed` pages, and will count items and votes only for these pages.

Efficient if you have lots of pages but need only `10` of them, eliminates unneeded counting.

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   page_views
        WHERE  page_views.page_id = pages.id
        ) AS views_count,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   page_items
        WHERE  page_items.page_id = pages.id
        ) AS items_count,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT SUM(vote)
        FROM   page_votes
        WHERE  page_votes.page_id = pages.id
        ), 0) AS votes_sum
FROM    pages
ORDER BY
        views_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Even more efficient query:

```
SELECT  pages.*,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   page_items
        WHERE  page_items.page_id = pages.id
        ) AS items_count,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT SUM(vote)
        FROM   page_votes
        WHERE  page_votes.page_id = pages.id
        ), 0) AS votes_sum
FROM    (
        SELECT  page_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    page_views
        GROUP BY
                page_id
        ORDER BY cnt DESC
        LIMIT 10
        ) AS pvd,
        pages
WHERE  pages.id = pvd.page_id
```

, eliminates unneeded joins with `pages`.

Comment: Thanks! The query you gave before editing worked. The optimized version gives me an error #1054 - Unknown column 'pages.id' in 'where clause'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I read your SQL correctly and you want the top 10 pages by views, try this:

```
SELECT p.*,
  (SELECT SUM(views) FROM page_views WHERE page_id = p.page_id) views,
  (SELECT SUM(votes) FROM page_votes WHERE page_id = p.page_id) votes,
  (SELECT SUM(items) FROM page_items WHERE page_id = p.page_id) items
FROM pages p
ORDER BY views DESC
LIMIT 10
```