# How to do SUM(VacancyID) without Duplicates while also showing Count(VacancyStartID) in the same Group?

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS 2005 I am reporting on all available posts by regional office, listed by region,office,vacancyID. 
I then display a total per office on how many people started in a particular vacancyID by doing a Count(VacancyStartID).
In the same group row with the Count(VacancyStartID) I need to display SUM(VacancyID).
However at present this does not give the correct SUM, because some vacancies have multiple VacancyStartID's and hence the vacancyID is listed few times, like so:

```
office vacancyID Number_of_vacancies       VacancyStartID (person who started a job)

 1         1              2                4567

 1         1              2                5678


Totals:                   4 (needs to be 2)    2
```

P.S. Note:These questions are not applicable in this instance:
 [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

[How do I remove "duplicate" rows from a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109640/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-view)

[Using multiple COUNTs and SUMs in a single SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620471/using-multiple-counts-and-sums-in-a-single-sql-statement)

Comment: In the underlying SQL call or in SSRS itself?

Comment: @greg: sorry, I mean in the SQL call related to the data source, or as a calculated value using the SSRS functions?

Comment: a calculated value using the SSRS functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the Underlying SQL Server call...

You can do [`...SUM(DISTINCT VacancyID)...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) like you can `COUNT (DISTINCT ..)`

Edit:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2, SUM(DISTINCT Number_of_vacancies)  as foo, COUNT (VacancyStartID) as bar
FROM
    MyView
...
```

If it's in the table or for a cell in the report, then there is no equivalent in the SSRS [SUM function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159134(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: It runs, but SUM(DISTINCT Number_of_vacancies) is not visible anywhere

Comment: @Greg: I answered your original question, before you edited! I've updated it and reformatted your question

Comment: I found it, but it does not display the correct amount, it is far too small

Comment: have you added the relevant group by etc?

Comment: I have spent half an hour to edit my question just like u did - how did u do it/

Comment: yeap, i did - it needs to be the same group as above

Comment: Do you want SUM(DISTINCT Number_of_vacancies) per vacancyID/office and COUNT(VacancyStartID) per office?

Comment: yes i do
SUM(DISTINCT Number_of_vacancies) per vacancyID/office and COUNT(VacancyStartID) per office

Comment: I am trying to give u another point, but it does not allow 2 points

Answer (score -1):

Do some grouping already in your query and then make a group with a simple Count in SSRS.